# How to run a new browser instance per test with Watir?

Tags: ruby, automation, rake, watir

When executing several tests in the same run, I've found that I get more errors than when I execute my tests one by one. While I look into this behaviour, I would like to have more accurate results by running a rake task that executes the tests I want, but runs every test on a new browser instance, like if I executed them one by one. This way I'll be able to have the same results as by doing it by hand, but avoiding the hassle of having to launch them one by one at the terminal.

I've searched for this feature in the documentation but haven't been able to find it, and the only similar question I found on Stack Overflow was related to Selenium, not watir.

Is it possible to do what I'm looking for? How?

Comment: What test framework are you using? And could you paste some of your test code?

Comment: I am using Ruby with Watir and Cucumber. I don't see how pasting some code would be useful, as the errors I'm getting are random everytime I run a rake task.

Comment: I do not see how we could help you if you do not provide some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm not making myself clear enough, but I think that by changing some config on the rake files should be enough?

I mean, I'm not asking how to fix my errors, what I want to know is if it's possible to run a rake task with a new browser instance per test.
Like: 
rake features:development (which has, for example, 50 tests)
Run test 1 -> open browser, execute test. Close browser.
Run test 2 -> open browser, execute test. Close browser.
What is happening when I run a rake task is: Run test 1 -> open browser, execute test, then run test 2 on the same browser window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you would want to create a Before hook to open the browser before each test and a After hook to close the browser after each test (see more on [hooks on the cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks))

Assuming you are starting your browser in the `support/env.rb`, you would replace your existing code with a before and after hook:

```
Before
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new
end

After
  @browser.close
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me to the hooks on the Cucumber Wiki.